# Cannot read property in event object

Tags: web3js, async

I am attempting to collect event information from a contract. When I call the event, I am attempting to collect a specific return value `event.returnValue.pubkey`. When I run the code below, I get the following type error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pubkey' of undefined`.

Can you help me determine why this is happening

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

// instantiate Deposit Contract and web3 interface
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://goerli.infura.io/v3/942365ea7fa043ac845ac1ba4aae57bc")); 
const abi = [{"name":"DepositEvent","inputs":[{"type":"bytes","name":"pubkey","indexed":false},{"type":"bytes","name":"withdrawal_credentials","indexed":false},{"type":"bytes","name":"amount","indexed":false},{"type":"bytes","name":"signature","indexed":false},{"type":"bytes","name":"index","indexed":false}],"anonymous":false,"type":"event"},{"outputs":[],"inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"_drain_address"}],"constant":false,"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"name":"get_deposit_root","outputs":[{"type":"bytes32","name":"out"}],"inputs":[],"constant":true,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":95389},{"name":"get_deposit_count","outputs":[{"type":"bytes","name":"out"}],"inputs":[],"constant":true,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":17683},{"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"inputs":[{"type":"bytes","name":"pubkey"},{"type":"bytes","name":"withdrawal_credentials"},{"type":"bytes","name":"signature"},{"type":"bytes32","name":"deposit_data_root"}],"constant":false,"payable":true,"type":"function","gas":1754607},{"name":"drain","outputs":[],"inputs":[],"constant":false,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":35793},{"name":"drain_address","outputs":[{"type":"address","name":"out"}],"inputs":[],"constant":true,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":663}];
const address = '0x0F0F0fc0530007361933EaB5DB97d09aCDD6C1c8';
const depositContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);


//helper function + instantiating variables
const first_block = 2845084
let unique_addresses = [];
let validatorcountperidentity = {};

let getEventProperty = async (block_start, block_end) => {
    
    let events;
    await depositContract.getPastEvents('DepositEvent', {fromBlock: block_start, toBlock: block_end})
        .then(results => { events = results });

    for (event of events) {

        if (!(event.returnValue.pubkey in unique_addresses)) {
            unique_addresses.push(event.returnValue.pubkey)

            // validatorcountperidentity[] 
        } 
    }
}

getEventProperty(first_block, first_block);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `event.returnValue` to `event.returnValues` and you should be able to access your event data. If still cannot access them start by debugging `results`.